# Relate a programmatically RelativeLayout's position with other already defined in the xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

In my xml I have:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainWeek"
    android:layout_height="387dip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/day1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        ...
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

in code I want something like:

```
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.day1);
    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, R.id.day1);

    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
    tv1.setText("A");
    layout.addView(tv1);

    this.addContentView(layout, rlp);
```

but the "layout" and its "tv1" appears on the top of the screen and not in below the "day1".
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you actually want the add the `layout` view to the `RelativeLayout` identified by the id `mainWeek`:

```
RelativeLayout mainWeek = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainWeek);
//Build the layout view object

mainWeek.addView(layout, rlp);
```

With the method `addContentView()`(i think) you append the layout view directly to the main window.